# Bind a repeater based on Collection Position

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater inside a repeater, and I trying to bind the child repeater with a list of Aka's from session.

My codebehind looks like:

```
     var results = HttpContext.Current.Session["completeRecord"];

     var rep = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptAkas");

     var akaList = new List<string>();

     foreach (Entity list in (IEnumerable<Entity>) results)
     {
         akaList.AddRange(list.Aka);
     }
     rep.DataSource = akaList;
     rep.DataBind();
```

In my child repeater I have the following:

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptAkas" OnItemDataBound="repeater_OnItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <p><strong>Aka</strong><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "akaList")  %>'></asp:Literal></p>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

this throws the following message:

**Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'akaList'.**

How can I bind this list to the repeater?

***EDIT***

Container.DataItem took care of it.

Comment: Does your "Entity" has a column named "akaList"?

Comment: I'm creating a new list based on the Entity, and then need to bind that list to the child repeater.

Comment: Did you try binding your reapeter to (IEnumerable<Entity>) results?

Comment: Hi Shashank, i got it to work using Container.DataItem, i just want to try it with some more data to confirm it does actually do what it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Container.DataItem` is **the current item your Repeater is iterating over**. It's not the list of strings, it's each string individually.

Think of what you're doing in a more pseudocode form:

```
foreach ( var a_single_string in Repeater.DataSource )
{
    var some_var = a_single_string.akaList;
}
```

When you reference `Container.DataItem`, it's the same as addressing `a_single_string` in the example above.

Not practically applicable code by a long shot, but I hope it explains why you are getting the error. You are actually asking for the property "akaList" of a **string**, hence the error.